# Use .NET 4.0 DLL on a machine with .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net

I am in the process of testing a program (class library). The class library (dll) is testing on various systems: .NET Frameworks 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0. Is it possible to test it on .NET 3.0 and 3.5 without having to upgrade the .NET version?

Comment: What do you mean by upgrade? What .net does your app target?

Comment: No.
See a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187212/net-3-5-runtime-and-net-4-runtime-compatibility

Comment: You must have .Net framework version at least as the target version when the dll has been created.

Comment: gideon: the target framework is 4.0.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can not do that, but its the other way around, you can test 3.5 dll on .Net framework 4.0.  An assembly compiled with .NET 4.0 can be loaded only by the CLR 4.0