# MSI fails to install because of missing .NET 3.5 although .NET 4.5 is installed

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I have a problem with msi installer made with WiX. It works on Win 7, but when I run it on Windows Server 2012 R2 it fails. It tries to install .NET framework 3.5 which you can't do that easily on Windows Server. The thing I don't understand is that .NET 4.5 framework is already installed on this machine.

[image: Windows Features - The following feature couldn't be installed]

Why does my wix installer look for .NET 3.5?

Is there a way how to disable it?

Thank you.

Update:
So I found the problem. One of components used in the installation was taken from an older source and this file wasn't compatible with .Net 4.0 and higher.
Thank you all who tried to help.

Comment: If the wix installer requires .net 3.5, it [includes some code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/682844/33499) to detect .net 3.5. You can simply remove that. If the application was build for .net 3.5, you might need to [retarget](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3187311/33499) it.

Comment: I couldn't find any code that checks for .net 3.5

Comment: It is also possible that a merge module that you include, checks for .net 3.5. Maybe you can show the exact error message in the question? You can also use orca.exe to examine the launch conditions in the msi. If you find it, you can also remove it with orca. But that needs to be done every time after rebuilding the msi. You need to download the windows sdk to get orca.

Comment: Here is the same error I get: [link](http://support.kaspersky.com/us/images/.Net88-264672.png)

Comment: Note that your errormessage says .net 3.5 cannot be installed. The screenshot looks like the windows wizard which tried to install .net 3.5, it does not look like a wix error. Maybe it is started using `ServerManagerCmd.exe` or powershell (`Add-WindowsFeature`). Anyway, for the same reason it is difficult to [manually install](http://superuser.com/q/850963/57579) .net 3.5, it is also difficult to do that automatically.

Comment: I understand that. But I can't find where msi tries to install .net. I am investigating InstallUtil right now. Could InstallUtil be responsible for .net installation?

Answer (score 1):

[Do you need both .net 3.5 and 4.0 installed or just .net 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642301/do-you-need-both-net-3-5-and-4-0-installed-or-just-net-4)

Not exactly what you're looking for, but it says that sometimes .net 3.5 is not fully replaced by .net 4.0 and higher. So you also need .net 3.5

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it. But by now, I came to the same conclusion, that .net 3.5 is also needed on Windows Server.